# SQL: How do I SELECT pair of a table objects with limited repetition for each object?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find different pairs of questions but in a way that each question repeats at most a few (like 5 which is not important) times in all of the pairs of the result.

I have a table of questions, and by Cartesian product of it on itself every question in first position repeats at least with all of other questions.

how can I limit the result to find question pairs with a few repetition for each question at of all?

the main table is something like this:

```
id  question
1   q1
2   q2
3   q3
4   q4
```

with Cartesian product I achieve

```
id1   question1  id2   question2
1     q1         2     q2
1     q1         3     q3
1     q1         4     q4
.
.
.
```

but I just want

```
id1   question1  id2   question2
1     q1         2     q2
3     q3         4     q4
```

(no more repetition for q1)

thanks in advance

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: "multiplying" is not an operation that I associate with rows on a table.  What query produces the results that you are getting.

Comment: SELECT 
    p1.Id as qid1,
  p1.Body as question1,
  p2.Id as qid2,
  p2.Body as question2,
  FROM Posts p1, Posts p2
  WHERE p1.Id <> p2.Id

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think he mean Cartesian product.

Comment: Do you want repeat or you dont want repeat? Because you say at most 5, but in your sample there isnt any repeat. So if you dont want repeat the number of question must be even. Otherwise if number is odd at least one question must be repeat.

Comment: it is a huge table, without any constraint every question repeats hundreds of times. a few time is acceptable but not in the hundreds scale.

Comment: Again do you want create the pairs? Or want select from a table already with the pairs? Be clear on what is your request. Also we need to know what is your RDBMS.

Comment: I want to create pairs form table of questions. and MySql

Answer (score 0):

if Id is continue sequence (no holes) you can pair one even id with one odd id.

```
 SELECT *
 FROM question Q1
 JOIN question Q2 
   ON Q1.ID = Q2.ID -1
 WHERE 
   Q1.ID % 2 <> 0
```

now if the number of question is odd you can add one aditional par for example the last question with the first one.

```
 UNION 
 SELECT *
 FROM question Q1
 JOIN question Q2 
 WHERE 
     Q1.ID = 1
 AND Q2.ID = (SELECT max(ID) FROM questions)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a small number of random question pairs, a much smaller number than N**2. Compute the Cartesian cross product, randomly shuffle it, and produce the first few rows.

```
select *  from crossproduct  order by sha1(qid1 + ',' + qid2)  limit 10;
```

assuming this setup:

```
drop table  if exists  posts;
create table posts (
  id     integer  primary key  auto_increment,
  body   varchar(80)
);

drop view  if exists  crossproduct;
create view crossproduct as
select p1.id as qid1, p1.body as question1,
       p2.Id as qid2, p2.Body as question2
from   posts p1, posts p2
where  p1.id != p2.id
;
```

To re-shuffle, use `sha1(qid1 + ', 1,' + qid2)`, or `, 2,`, ....